# How to use the ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, process, builder

I am trying to use the `ProcessBuilder` to make java communicate with an external program (`Prolog`).

I understand how to set the environment variables and have done this.

But I don't understand how I communicate with the process, how I give an input to it, how I get the output from it, how the errors are handled. I believe I need to use an input stream the get the output from prolog, an input stream for the errors from `Prolog`, and an output stream to give prolog the input. Can somebody tell me how I use these streams to communicate with the program?

Here is what I have so far (let me know if I'm thinking wrong at some point)

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("gprolog");
//Enviroment variable to disable the gui for prolog
pb.environment().put("LINEDIT", "gui=no");
InputStream in = pb.getInputStream();
InputStream err = pb.getErrorStream();
OutputStream out = pb.getOutputStream();
pb.start();
```

How do I give a command to prolog after this?